# Create Controller in MVC for comments and feedbacks

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-controller

I have created a create controller for comments and feedback i have one issue with that , I cannot add new comments using that controller i.e. if i have already added a comment against some ID it will gives me option to edit that comments. But i want that it saves the old comments and allows me to add a new comment against that id. please help i am pasting my controller here.

```
   public ActionResult CreateNote(int id)
    {
        YelloAdminDbContext db = new YelloAdminDbContext();
        var feedBack = db.SaveFeedBack.Find(id);

        if (feedBack != null && feedBack.feedback.FeedBackDrpDown == "Interested - Call Back After 1 month")
        {

            var temp = db.Note.Find(id);

            if (temp != null)
            {
                temp.CallBAckDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(36);
                return View(temp);
            }
            else
            {
                return View(new CallNote { LoginId = id, FormFillDate = DateTime.Now, CallBAckDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30) });
            }


        }
        if (feedBack != null && feedBack.feedback.FeedBackDrpDown == "Not Available - Call Back After One Day")
        {

            var temp = db.Note.Find(id);

            if (temp != null)
            {
                temp.CallBAckDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(15);
                return View(temp);
            }
            else
            {
               return View(new CallNote { LoginId = id, FormFillDate = DateTime.Now, CallBAckDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) });
            }


        }
        if (feedBack != null && feedBack.feedback.FeedBackDrpDown == "Currently using yello - Call Back After Two Months")
        {

            var temp = db.Note.Find(id);

            if (temp != null)
            {
                temp.CallBAckDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);
                return View(temp);
            }
            else
            {
                return View(new CallNote { LoginId = id, FormFillDate = DateTime.Now, CallBAckDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2) });
            }


        }

    return View(new CallNote { LoginId = id, FormFillDate = DateTime.Now, CallBAckDate = null});

    }
    public bool DoesExist(int loginId)
    {
        YelloAdminDbContext db = new YelloAdminDbContext();
        if (db.Note.Find(loginId) == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateNote(CallNote callnote)
    {


        YelloAdminDbContext db = new YelloAdminDbContext();


        //if (DoesExist(callnote.LoginId))
        //{

        //    db.Entry(callnote).State = EntityState.Modified;
        //    db.SaveChanges();
        //    return JavaScript("alert('success');");
        //}

        //else   
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Note.Add(callnote);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Content("Success");

        }

        return Content("Error");
    }
```

Here is create note view

```
      @model MyYello.Admin.Models.CallNote

  @{
ViewBag.Title = "CreateNote";
  }
 @*<body onload="JavaScript:AutoRefresh(30000);">*@
 <body>
<h2>Comments and Feed Back</h2>
<div>
    <h3>Curent Feed Back Value
        <br />
        @{Html.RenderAction("DisplayFeedBack", "Admin");}
    </h3>
    @{Html.RenderAction("SelectFeedBack", "Admin");}
   </div>
   @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateNote", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
   {@Html.ValidationSummary(true);
      <fieldset>

        @Html.HiddenFor(item => item.LoginId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(item => item.FormFillDate)
        <legend>Comments and Feedback</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(item => item.Comments, "Staff Comments")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(item => item.Comments)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => item.Comments)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(item => item.FeedBackBox, "Custommer Feedback")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(item => item.FeedBackBox)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => item.FeedBackBox)
        </div>

       <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(item => item.CallBAckDate, "Call Back Date")

        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(item => item.CallBAckDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => item.CallBAckDate)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="Submit" value="Create" id="Create" />
        </p>

      </fieldset>



   }

</body>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
  function AutoRefresh(t) {
     setTimeout("location.reload(true);", t);
}
 </script>
```

Comment: This is confusing. Is a callnote the same thing as a comment?

Comment: yes it is named as callnote

Comment: I think we need to see the `CreateNote` View, or at least the form that POSTs to your action method.

Comment: View is simple and i have added it now.